# Problem loading pages as a site owner when Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) is active

Tags: 2013, web-template, mds

We have created a custom teamsite webtemplate, which has some extra site columns, contenttypes, lists and libraries. No fancy stuff.

However we got some complaints that sometimes, not always pages are loaded after a few minutes or not at all. After some research I saw that the problem only occurred when a user is a **site owner** and when the **minimal download strategy** is active?

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it, beside disabling de minimal download strategy ?